# FusedLocationProviderClient - type or namespace could not be found (error)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, fusedlocationproviderclient

So sorry if this is really simple (also failing to install google play services on Marshmallow emulator, and getting a tad wound up!).

I am aiming to get GPS data in a Xamarin Android C# project on Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.3).

I am following the Xamarin Location Services walkthrough (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location#using-the-fused-location-provider) and source code examples.  I have tried targeting Android 6.0 (my preferred) and also 7.1 and MonoAndroid6 and MonoAndroid71, respectively.

I have definitely installed the NuGet packages for Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Location, .Maps and the required 'base' libraries (.Base, .Basement and .Tasks) - versions 32.961.0 and 42.1021.1 (target dependant).

The following code tells me "The type or namespace name 'FusedLocationProviderClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
```

I have used Object Browser to explore the libraries, and do not even see FusedLocationProviderClient (just FusedLocationProviderApi - which I also read on SO is deprecated...).

Should I be using the 'older' Location Service APIs to target 6.0, or am I missing something else?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three APIs levels involved in a `Xamarin.Android` project, one is Xamarin specific, that is the one `Target Framework`, **not** to be confused with the `Target Android Version` that sets the `targetSdkVersion` in the app's Manifest.

> `Target Framework` – Specifies which framework to use in building your application. This API level is used at compile time by Xamarin.Android.
>
> `Minimum Android Version` – Specifies the oldest Android version that you want your app to support. This API level is used at run time by Android.
>
> `Target Android Version` – Specifies the version of Android that your app is intended to run on. This API level is used at run time by Android.

Set your `Target Framework` to the latest and greatest (currently 8.1), the  `Target Android Version` to `6.0` and (re-)install your packages.

Understanding Android API Levels : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, very useful!  While (re)installing, I needed to remove some lingering references directly in the csproj file, causing problems, but we're all working now - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Surprised it's not in the documentation.