# Xamarin forms not deploying to Android stimulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I m working on a Xamarin Forms project Using Visual Studio 2017, I deployed the project once to the Android Emulator, I didn't change anything after that  and again deployed it several times every time I'm getting deploy failed with warnings. I have attached the warnings here.
[image]

Comment: Update your Xamarin `Target Framework` to at least  `7.1` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615134/fusedlocationproviderclient-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-error/49617121#49617121 Then Clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: Add error/warning message here, please

Comment: Can you check in VS go to Build > Configuration Manager and check deploy is tick or not in android ,if it is not you can tick and check otherwise please see the output window for exact error details